# Use array values in a formula - vba

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Would really appreaciate a friendly nudge to the right direction.

I am trying to use an array as a variable to populate a column with values based on COUNTIFS formula, like "a cell - a formula with new element of the array as a variable".
So AF2 - Countifs for Brand2
   AF3 - Countifs for Brand3
..
 Now I get the value ONLY for the final element of the array (and I can see how excel loops through the rest) for the whole range. Tried more or less everything known to me and looked through earlier questions - to no avail. Would appreciate a little help.

[image: How it would look graphically]

```
Option Explicit
Sub Summa_po()

Dim Mesyaz1 As Date
Dim Mesyaz2 As Date
Dim Mesyaz3 As Date
Dim Brand()
Dim i As Long

Worksheets(1).Activate

Mesyaz1 = DateAdd("m", -1, Now)
Mesyaz2 = DateAdd("m", -2, Now)
Mesyaz3 = DateAdd("m", -3, Now)
Brand = Array("Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3", "Brand4")
For i = LBound(Brand) To UBound(Brand) 'Here I tried also For i=0 to UBound(Brand)
With ActiveSheet.Range("AF:AF")
.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & ",H:H,""Head"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"
.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("AF2:AF55") 'I used to draw it to the last cell but it is not a problem appararently
  End With
  Next i

[AF1] = "Head"
End Sub
```

Comment: But, what your problem is? Do you receive an error? If yes, what error and on which code line. If not, what does your code produces against what you need?

Comment: As I written, the column is getting populated by the formula with the last element of the array. So e.g. (C:C;12;H:H;"Head";F:F;"Brand 4"). Brand 1, Brand2, Brand3 are not saved

Comment: Some sample data would help. You are applying the formula to the whole column (which is going to take a while - pretty sure is not what you want) and you're repating the process for the 4 brands. Question: How do you decide which brand should be included in the formula?

Comment: But, this is what your code does. Please put a `Stop` before `End With` and check the formulas when code stops. You will see that it uses the second array element (for the first you have to use 0) and then the third one. The previous formulas will be replaced by that last iteration... How do you like tho formulas to really look?

Comment: That is the question - I want this formula work for every brand. It is the only varaible that changes here dynamically. So I want a column contains in this case with four unique values,

Comment: I am afraid you do not understand the point... Your code does exactly what you explained it does, but you look to be unsatisfied. I cannot understand what you REALLY want from it. Can you post here two consecutive formulas like you need to be iterated? Like they should be returned on your Excel sheet...

Comment: What would be the formula if you do it manually directly in Excel (not vba)? Something like this...`=COUNTIFS(C:C,12;H:H,"Head",F:F,"Brand1") + COUNTIFS(C:C,12,H:H,"Head",F:F,"Brand2") + COUNTIFS(C:C,12,H:H,"Head",F:F,"Brand3") + COUNTIFS(C:C,12,H:H,"Head",F:F,"Brand4")`

Comment: Looks like you’re overwriting the formula for the entire AF column on each iteration, so only the last value (Brand4) is kept in the end. I guess you should set formula for each cell individually instead of using autofill (although I don’t know how should it scale to rows 5-55, since you only have four brands). Another approach could be adding a hidden column with brands and reference it in the formula.

Comment: Would you like that your formula to be applied only for four rows, each of it referring to one of your array elements? Would you really need that all the column to be populated with a formula?

Comment: @AlexSkalozub You got the point - it overwrites the values, yet, i want value to be preserved in a cell and the next cell to contain the value for the next brand. There are like 50 brands in my array - that is why the range is up to cell 50 something.

Comment: Then, your approach is wrong. You must not apply your formula to your column! You have to define each cell where the formula to be applied according to your iteration number. Something like "AF" & i...

Comment: @RicardoDiaz yes, you are right - added the pic of the example

Comment: @Anna check the answer and let me know if it works

Comment: @FaneDuru No, I want to extend filling only up to the pount there are branda. In my actual data base there are 50 of them. But this method worked so far with other formulas.

Comment: Then, try replacing of your iteration code with the one proposed by me in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your explanation doesn't match your code, but re-reading them and your last image confirmed what I suspected.

Read the comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**EDIT:** Adjusted the counter for the brand array

**Code:**

```
Sub Summa_po()

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Dim Mesyaz1 As Date
    Dim Mesyaz2 As Date
    Dim Mesyaz3 As Date
    Dim Brand() As Variant

    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Dim counter As Long

    ' If you need to work with a specific sheet change the next line to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NAME OF THE SHEET")
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    ' Define brands array
    Brand = Array("Brand1", "Brand2", "Brand3", "Brand4")

    ' Define start row
    firstRow = 2

    ' Find last row in column AF uncomment next line
    ' lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Or set directly the last row
    lastRow = 55

    ' Calc previous months
    Mesyaz1 = DateAdd("m", -1, Date)
    Mesyaz2 = DateAdd("m", -2, Date)
    Mesyaz3 = DateAdd("m", -3, Date)

    ' Define the target range in column AF
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("AF" & firstRow & ":AF" & lastRow)

    ' Loop through each cell in range
    For Each cell In targetRange.Cells

        If counter = UBound(Brand) + 1 Then
            counter = 1
        Else
            counter = counter + 1
        End If

        cell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & Month(Mesyaz3) & ",H:H,""Head"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(counter - 1) & Chr(34) & ")"

    Next cell

    ' Are you assigning this to a name? better use Thisworkbook.Names("")
    [AF1] = "Head"

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! There is a Run-time error 9, subsript out of range on the cell.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & ",H:H,""Head"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(counter - 1) & Chr(34) & ")"   Will delve into it, may be will manage to fix it

Comment: I have adjusted the way to manage the array counter. Please replace the code with the new one and adjust it accordingly. Let me know how it goes

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you so much for teaching me the method! It's fantactic!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your next code:

```
    For i = LBound(Brand) To UBound(Brand) 'Here I tried also For i=0 to UBound(Brand)
        With ActiveSheet.Range("AF:AF")
            .Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & ",H:H,""Head"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"
            .AutoFill Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("AF2:AF55") 'I used to draw it to the last cell but it is not a problem appararently
       End With
   Next i
```

With the next one:

```
  For i = LBound(Brand) To UBound(Brand) 
        Range("AF" & i + 2).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(C:C," & RTrim(Month(Mesyaz3)) & _
                   ",H:H,""Head"",F:F," & Chr(34) & Brand(i) & Chr(34) & ")"
  Next i
```

`AutoFill` does not make any sense here. There is not any reference to be iterated for your Brands. They must be added only by the code...

Comment: You are my personal Jesus - saved me from a two day agony! You are absolutely right - Autofill was the bug!!!

Comment: @Anna: I am afraid, not exactly... `AutoFill` was only the bad circumstance. The trick has been done especially by using `Range.("AF" & i)`. Otherwise, your iteration created a formula on all column, but referring to the last array element...

Comment: Guru, yeah, I realize it. Just never came across this method of populating a range. It is so elegant. Have been around VBA not too long.